# I need to Click on table cell value of a web page in automation anywhere tool

Tags: html, automationanywhere

I am new to Automation Anywhere. I am trying to click on specific cell value of a web page table.

I have cloned the table object and applied action "Click on cell by index" provided by automation anywhere tool on specific row and column.

Secondly, I tried Mouse Click functionality but, on search base position of cell where to click will not always be the same that's why cant implement mouse click.

Screenshot is attached what I have done so far, Nothing happens by click on the cell. I want to click on the value present in the cell.

[image]

I want to click on highlighted portion mentioned in below screenshot:
[image]

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach a screenshot of the full search criteria? I'm sure it has to be something with the path and DomXpath.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that below points have been checked:

- The object properties should be unique and non changing. This is required to identify the object correctly during execution
- Check whether object cloning is working properly with current screen resolution. If not, you need to change the screen resolution